# Looking for a smart contract event listening tool for self indexing

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, subgraph, moralis

Looking for a fast lightweight library/tool that can listen to the event emitted from smart contract in a self-hosted web api.  The historical record don’t have to be tracked, only need the latest block data. Tools like Moralis and Subgraph is not customizable and fast enough.

A idea tool/library will look something like this

```
event = SubscribeToEvent([{
    address: “0x…”
    event: “FooEvent”
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this will do exactly what you want, it might do, but you could listen to the pending txpool with `web3.geth`

```
def pool(address):
    txpoolContent = web3.geth.txpool.content()
    pendingTxPool = txpoolContent['pending']
    if address in pendingTxPool:
        txpool = pendingTxPool[address].values()
        for value in txpool:
            if "FooEvent" in value['input']:
```

Where address is the address you're looking for.

Address could be the owner of the smart contract to track events of the smart contract.